# How to print in decimal form rather than exponential form in perl

Tags: perl, decimal, exponential

I have written a program in perl.My requirement is to print the only the decimal numbers, not exponential numbers. Could you please let me know how to implement this ?
My program is calculating the expression 1/2 power(n) , where n can take up integer numbers from 1 to 200 only. And only 100 lines should be printed.

Example: 
N=1, print 0.5 
N=2, print 0.25

My program looks like:

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   my $exp;
   my $num;
   my $count_lines = 0;
   while($exp = <>)
   {
        next if($exp =~ m/^$/);
        if($exp > 0 and $exp <=200 and $count_lines < 100)
        {
            $num = 1/(2 ** $exp);
            print $num,"\n";
            $count_lines++;
       }
  }
```

Input values:
If N = 100 , then out is getting printed in exponential form. But, the requirement is it should get printed in decimal form.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `print` will pick the "best" format to display the value, so it chooses scientific format for very large or very small numberss to avoid printing a long string of zeroes.

But you can use [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) (the format specifiers are documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)) to format a number however you want.

0.5<sup>200</sup> is a very small number, so you need around 80 decimal places

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $exp = <>) {

  next unless $exp =~ /\S/;
  my $count_lines = 0;

  if ($exp > 0 and $exp <= 200 and $count_lines < 100) {
    my $num = 1 / (2 ** $exp);
    printf "%.80f\n", $num;
    $count_lines++;
  }
}
```

**output** for 100

```
0.00000000000000000000000000000078886090522101181000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and for 200

```
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000062230152778611417000
```

If you would like to remove insignificant trailing zeroes then you can use `sprintf` to put the formatted number into a variable and then use `s///` to delete trailing zeroes, like this

```
my $number = sprintf "%.80f", $num;
$number =~ s/0+$//;
print $number, "\n";
```

which gives

```
0.00000000000000000000000000000078886090522101181
```

and

```
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000062230152778611417
```

**Note** that the true value of the calculation has many more digits than this, and the accuracy of the result is limited by the size of the floating point values that your computer uses.

Answer (score 1):

`0.5 ^ 200` is too small for a double floating point number, you need to use `Math::BigFloat`, that will overload basic math operations and output operators such as `print` for you, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::BigFloat;

my $x = Math::BigFloat->new('0.5');
my $y = Math::BigFloat->new('200');

print $x ** $y, "\n";
```

---

Or use `bignum`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use bignum;

print 0.5 ** 200, "\n";
```

Output:

```
$ perl t.pl 
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000062230152778611417071440640537801242405902521687211671331011166147896988340353834411839448231257136169569665895551224821247160434722900390625
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using Perl Packages.

Comment: @ShubhraGarg It is possible, but not an easy task.

Comment: how to do it using number theory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) or [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to specify the format of what you want to print out.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $num = 0.000000123;

printf("%.50", $num)
```

If you need something like Perl 5 formats, take a look at [`Perl6::Form`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl6-Form-0.04/Form.pm) (note, this is a Perl 5 module, it just implements the proposed Perl 6 version of formats).